# What is the symbol *.* called?

Tags: command, special-characters

What's the name for the

```
*.*
```

symbol and what is its significance?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Interpretation of `*.*` under old Windows/DOS systems

The significance here is more related to Windows/DOS than to Unix/Linux. On old Windows/DOS systems it was a 'wildcard' pattern. Wildcard patterns were used for matching filenames in a similar manner to Unix globs. The `*.*` wildcard was commonly used to match any file.

As with a Unix glob, the `*` will match any sequence of characters in a filename, as such `*` on its own will also match any file. However the reason why `*.*` will match any filename too is due to differences in the way that these wildcards work. According to [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071217-00/?p=24143):

> Any characters other than a dot that come after an asterisk have no effect, since the asterisk moves the cursor to position 12, at which point nothing changes the parse state except for a dot, which clears the last three positions and moves the cursor.

This behaviour (somewhat odd from Unix perspective) means that a dot following a `*` does not actually match a dot, but is just a hackish way to allow you to add more characters to the pattern. This means that adding another `*` will match anything in these last three positions.

This makes a little more sense when you consider that the syntax was used on DOS and old Windows systems before Windows 95 which required [8.3 filenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename). These filenames were only allowed to have one dot and at most three characters following the dot. Most, if not all files on the system would have a three character extension (even though technically a shorter or no extension was allowed), so somehow I guess it made sense to use `*.*` to match any file (at least from a warped Windowsey logic perspective).

#### Interpretation of `*.*` in Unix shells

In Unix shells, as others have pointed out, this represents a 'pathname expansion' or 'glob.' The `*` does not have any odd jumping to the end behaviour and thus does not lead to characters following it being ignored. `*.*` pattern will match any filename containing a dot (except at the start). This will definitely not match any file as there are many files on a Unix/Linux system that *don't* have an extension (or otherwise contain a dot since this is allowed too).

The reason for `*.*` not matching a dot at the start of filenames on Unix is because putting a dot at the start is how files are 'hidden' and hidden files are excluded from globs by default. To match them in a POSIX shell, a dot needs to be put explicitly at the start of the pattern. In `bash` the `dotglob` shell option can be set or the `GLOBIGNORE` variable can be set appropriately, but this is another question!

Comment: It should be noted that current Windows versions seem to behave more logically. In particular, "Any characters other than a dot that come after an asterisk have no effect" is not true anymore; at least when filtering files in a standard *Open File* dialog on Windows 7 by the pattern `*7.*`, get all files whose last character before the extension is a `7`, and with `*sa*`, I get all files that contain the substring `sa` anywhere in there filename, and so on. (Accordingly, the article you cite is titled *How **did** wildcards work **in MS-DOS**?* (emphasis added by myself).)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, updated the headers to reflect this. This behaviour is pre Windows 95, which is in the answer (although the header was misleading).

Answer (score 12):

It's [`glob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) in `bash`. Below I have quoted from the bash manual:

> #### [bash - GNU Bourne-Again SHell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)
>
> `*`
>
> Matches  any string, including the null string. When the `globstar` shell option is enabled, and `*` is used in a pathname expansion context, two adjacent `*s` used as a single pattern will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If followed by a `/`, two adjacent `*s` will match only directories and subdirectories.

In this case, `*.*` match any files that contain a dot `.` in its name.

You can see more details [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).

Answer (score 8):

The asterisk `*` is a `glob` in shell language.  Quoting from [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13_02):

> The asterisk ( `'*'` ) is a pattern that shall match any string, including the null string.

However, it doesn't match filenames beginning with a `.` unless the shell option `dotglob` is set.

When you use `*.*`, it matches anything that:

- does not start with a `.`
- contains at least one `.`

You might also want to refer to [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) in the manual.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of people coming from Windows think `*.*` is for all files. On Windows, it is. On UNIX, it is all files that contain at least 1 dot in their name. `*` by itself works just fine in Windows (however *.* is required in DOS); however the old textbooks published `*.*` and it seems to be a hard habit to break.

Answer (score 4):

`*` is a wildcard used by the shell to perform *[filename expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)*, also known as "globbing".  `*` expands to anything, including nothing (e.g, `*.*` will match `file.`, etc.).  The other common wildcard is `?`, which matches any single character.

Do not confuse the function of these wildcards with the use of the same characters in regular expressions (such as those used with grep).

Answer (score 3):

Here there are actually 2 symbols, asterisk `*` and dot `.`. The shells normally only interpret the asterisk as any character, but in regex it would mean a greedy glob. In this case it would match anything that doesn't end or start with a dot, but contains at least one:

```
somefile.dot # match
.dot.between.words. # match
.onlydotatstart # don't match
onlydotatend. # match
.startandenddot. # don't match
```

Comment: Your `onlydotatend.` case is a match, surely?

Comment: @Graeme nope. `touch 'onlydotatend.' && echo *.*` doesn't return it

Comment: Does for me! On both `bash` and `dash`. What shell are you using?

Comment: @Graeme zsh, and you are right bash doesn't.

Comment: I just tried this on a vanilla `zsh` configuration and it works there too. I don't understand how `onlydotatend.` can't be a match, is there a configuration option that does this?

Comment: @Graeme weird, I tested again and now it match it. Changed my answer. Apparently I had something somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

That is **star-dot-star** — at least, in the DOS (and later, of course, Windows) world. In DOS, the dot `.` has special magical meaning, because filenames are an eight-character base (later extended, but let's stay old school) and a three-character extension (which defined the file type). In Unix, file type is usually defined by the first two bytes of the file (or other magic), and the extension is informative but doesn't carry much meaning. Except for when this has all gotten blurred.

So, in Unix, there is no special meaning. The asterisk is a "globbing" character in Unix shells and is wildcard for any number of characters (including zero). `?` is another common globbing character, matching *exactly one* of any character.

`*.*` matches any filenames which contain at least one `.`. It doesn't have a special name or any meaning any more than `*a*` or `*_*`.  And `*.?` would match any files with a dot and exactly one character after that dot. There are also some more complicated extended globbing patterns — see your shell's man page.

The "New Hacker's Dictionary" (an expansion of the old MIT "Jargon File") notes that "star" is the most common name for the `*` symbol (followed by `splat`), and I think that's still true in practice, and `.` is definitely commonly "dot", so, while it doesn't have any intrinsic special meaning as a conglomerated symbol, the sequence is still reasonably called **star-dot-star** on Unix. (It's just less useful.)

Comment: This might sound strange but thank you for mentioning "star dot star", it's what made this page googleable!